# What to wear for job interview

Tags: interviewing, student, first-job, part-time

I am currently a PhD at a decent university in Math and applying for a part time grad student job in a Fintech company in one of the major centers for finance. I applied for the job by responding to an e-mail and now they asked me to do an onsite interview. The entire application process was informal since they always addressed me by my first name and now I wonder what I should wear. I just wonder whether wearing a suit might be weird in this case?

Comment: Maybe you should ask about that crazy toupée instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> applying for a part time grad student job in a Fintech company in one
>   of the major centers for finance....and now I wonder what I should
>   wear.

Treat this as you would any other formal job interview.

Wear a formal business suit, including plain shirt and an inoffensive tie (No cartoon characters).

Wear good, formal shoes - not patent leather ("dress" shoes). Plain black/grey/white socks (basically again, not things with cartoons.

Your choice of underwear, but definitely something and comfortable.

Accessorize - belt, and cufflinks if appropriate. Go for simple. Do not wear braces (US "suspenders").

Comment: thank you, actually I am not a troll, I just used a fancy name to attract attention. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DonaldTrump so you deliberately choose a name evoking a controversial figure in order to get attention. It might not *quite* qualify as trolling but it's not far off.

Comment: @DonaldTrump Welcome to the site. All new questions attract attention and (almost always) get answered seriously by one of the many hundreds of users on here, whether you have that moniker or the default userNNNNNN (apologies to anyone with that actual username), a) to help you in your problem, and b) to provide guidance for future visitors here.

Comment: @Justin well said.

Comment: It's always better to overdress for an interview than risk under-dressing. Although if you can find out about the company dress culture in advance, then you could go for a slightly smarter than default option (IE smart casual shirt and jumper, no tie, for a place where people where casual shirts / t-shirts)

Comment: *white* socks? With a suit? Seriously?

Comment: @Owain - Maybe I should have said so explicitly, but I just meant "avoid colours / patterns". Nothing wrong with those, but at an interview, I'd go for neutral, as no inferences can be drawn. Having said that, a couple of years ago I had black socks with weekday names on, which one of the interview panel noticed. I pointed out that month names probably sent the wrong message and continued talking about [tech thing]. Got the job.

Comment: And make sure your tie is the right length (OP especially)